# How to call eager loading on a column other than user?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have `Review` and `User` models. In the `User` modal, I have `hasMany('App\Review')` and in the `Review`s model I have `belongsTo('App\User')`. I call this:

```
Review::where('user_id', $user)->with('user')->paginate(4);
```

This works and I get the user who wrote the review and the review itself: 
[image]

However, in the Reviews table, I also have the person who they reviewed (called `fulfiller_id`). I want to load each review with the user who got reviewed. I did something like this:

```
Review::where('user_id', $user)->with('fulfiller_id')->paginate(4);
```

but that gives me an error:

> Call to undefined relationship [fulfiller_id] on model [App\Review].

How do I go about also attaching the `user` under the `fulfiller_id` along with each `review`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a second relationship on the `Review` model:

**Review.php**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function fulfiller()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'fulfiller_id');
}
```

Then you can load:

```
Review::where('user_id', $user)->with(['user','fulfiller'])->paginate(4);
```

Comment: Great! Silly me, I created that method but didn't put the method name and instead put fulfiller_id in the with the method. Thank you so much!